# I am looking for the right significance test for a questionnaire

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, proportion

I have a questionnaire to check the implementation of several recommended health improving measurements. It will look approximately like this:

1. Did you do your 20 minute Yoga routine on a daily basis?
   Answers possible: Yes / No / partly
2. Did you increase your protein intake?
   Answers possible: Yes / No / partly
3. Did you employer provide ergonomic office furniture?
   Answers possible: Yes / No / partly

And so on.

The population consists of 7000 participants.
My hypothesis is, for each measure separately, that the majority of participants did not implement the measures or only partially implemented them
I have two questions:

1. Which test to use to test this hypothesis?
2. How to calculate the necessary sample size?

Comment: As a side note, given the form of your survey questions, maybe you should be wary of acquiescence bias. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquiescence_bias

Comment: Why do you need to test this? You can calculate the proportion of people with "yes" answers for each question and then you know if the majority of participants (said they) did it or not.

Comment: Yes, I can calculate the proportions for the sample. But what I want to know is if the difference in proportions is significant so that I can infer from my sample to the population